# Pop up a alert box with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With Rails I love how you can just do,

`link_to "Click", some_path, :data => {:confirm => "Are you sure?"}`.

Is there a simple way to pop up an alert dialog instead? Could I try something like,

`link_to "Click", some_path, :data => {:ALERT => "Are you sure?"}`?

Answer (score 1):

Rails only supports `:confirm` out of the box, because it's convenient for delete links. All it really does is add "data-confirm" attribute to  html tag, then javascript logic is applied to any tag that has this attribute. You could make your 2nd version work by adding your own javascript code, similar to how confirm works.

You can see the code that makes `:confirm` possible here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js